# VS2010 Web Load Testing with User Logins

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing, webtest

I am looking to create a Web Performance test that can be bound to a CSV file with usernames and passwords so that I can run concurrent tests with different users. How do I modify a recorded WebTest in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [Walkthrough: Adding Data Binding to a Web Performance Test (CSV File)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385833.aspx)?

Comment: this will work with more than user being logged in with diferent session?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have added the csv file as a datasource to the webtest,

1. right click on the webtest.
2. select "properties"
3. set the username property to the
   correct datasource field
4. set the password property likewise