# asp.net mvc user load testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, load-testing

I need to login in about 100 users each with their own session to test a web application. I need to then have some users do some activity.

Which tool can I use to login many users each with their own session?

Comment: maybe this can help: http://seleniumhq.org/ I am just not sure if it can simulate 100 users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definetely use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition if you have it.
Make sure you set the [Percentage of New Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406980.aspx) property to 100 in the load test properties.

Comment: database call with a coded webtest. Otherways to skin a cat though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763872/vs2010-web-load-testing-with-user-logins

Answer (score 0):

Our product, Web Performance Load Tester, does that, as do most load testing tools.